# Como carregar automaticamente opções definidas no system.xml quando for mudado o tema no painel admin?

Tags: magento

Estou querendo que meu módulo fique bem posicionado em 2 temas: RWD e Default.

Como defino isso no `system.xml` do mesmo?

No caso pro RWD *package* as opções já estão funcionando e tudo, porem quando o *admin* muda de tema de: "RWD" para: "Default" quero que carregue as opções **SOMENTE** do tema *Default* e esconder as do "RWD"!

Na config do meu módulo dentro do Sistema > configuração > Empresa: Módulo (CONFIG , para abrir as opções) e já subir as opções exclusivas que farei pra esse tema. Como fazer isso?

OBs: magento versão 1.9.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já resolvi..... no caso o problema é que o módulo customizado funciona para um tema X, beleza, para funcionar em outro tema é necessário recriar as configs e subpastas dentro do outro tema.... no meu caso:
copiar o .XML do módulo da pasta app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout para app/design/frontend/base/default/layout resolveu. Obrigado!